# Upload and justify the image position of profile pic in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, avatar

Need the upload profile feature with following functionality:

1. Uploaded image validations. (type, size)
2. Save the image in a different   directory.
3. After uploading user should be able to re-position the image properly, so that the avatar looks
   properly aligned as the users wants.
4. Crop the image.

What are the solutions to implement this in ASP.Net with C# ?

Answer (score 1):

for croping image please read these article

1. [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/03/using-asp-net-and-jcrop-to-crop-images-online.aspx)
2. [codeplex](http://webcropimage.codeplex.com/)

there will be problems if you save image to different folders ie folder permission the domain host companies do give permission read only if you save it to another folder you have to give permissions to each folder. there is another way you make a root  folder with read and write permissions and then in that folder save your username name of folder

you can get the size and width and height if you use [valum](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)